# In case of smb server resume data is always nil when invoking cancelByProducingResumeData:

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest, download, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am downloading a file from smb server and want to give functionality of pause and resume but when I press cancel gives resumeData nil. This is because header does not contain etag or last-modified fields. Is there any work around in case of downloading from smb servers? I want to have resumeData in case of downloading files from smb server as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is few things which the server and client has to follow to get the data. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiondownloadtask/1411634-cancelbyproducingresumedata?language=objc

Comment: If the headers don't provide that information, then there's no way to know whether it is safe to resume the download.  You'll have to use a server that provides those headers (or a CGI script that does).